# Blob PDF data not rendering in IE 11

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, pdf-reader, ie11-developer-tools

I am getting blob data from API in below format.

```
const data = 'JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9MKMzQgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZw0KL1BhZ2VzIDcgMCBSDQovTWV0YWRhdGEgMjYgMCBSDQo+Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQozNSAwIG9iag0KPDwgL1R5cGUgL09ialN0bSAvTGVuZ3RoIDQxMCAvRmlyc3QgMTQ1IC9OIDIxIC9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlID4+DQpzdHJlYW0NCnicxdTBqhoxFAbgvTDv8L/A7ck5SSYT..............';
```

I have used below code to render PDF in IE, Chrome and Firefox.

```
    openPDF(pdfData: string){
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(atob(pdfData).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'}));
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.open(url);
    }else{
      window.open(url);
    }
  }
```

above code working fine and opening PDF in Chrome and Firefox, but same code not working in IE 11, and display **Access is denied.** error in console.

I tried below code, but giving error as attached,

```
let newBlob = new Blob([pdfData], {type: "application/pdf"});
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
```

[image]

I tried with iFrame as well, and it was opening blank PDF.

I have tried below code as well, which is downloading PDF in local system, but while opening file it display same error as above.

```
let newBlob = new Blob([pdfData], {type: "application/pdf"});
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(newBlob, 'one.pdf');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> const data =
>   'JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9MKMzQgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZw0KL1BhZ2VzIDcgMCBSDQovTWV0YWRhdGEgMjYgMCBSDQo+Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQozNSAwIG9iag0KPDwgL1R5cGUgL09ialN0bSAvTGVuZ3RoIDQxMCAvRmlyc3QgMTQ1IC9OIDIxIC9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlID4+DQpzdHJlYW0NCnicxdTBqhoxFAbgvTDv8L/A7ck5SSYT..............';

From your code, it seems that the data is base-64 encoded string, before using the msSaveOrOpenBlob or the msSaveBlob method to download it, we need to Decode the base-64 encoded string and convert to a ByteArray. Please refer to the following code (it works well on my side):

```
            var data = "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";
            var fileName = "testpdf.pdf";
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { 
                var byteCharacters = window.atob(data);
                var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
                }
                var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);  
            }
```

Besides, when you select the folder to store the pdf file, please check the folder properties and make sure you have the Write and Read permission.